# Keeping my production webserver updated

Tags: centos, security, webserver

I have a production webserver (CentOS 6.5) and I just wanted to know how do I keep this updated interms of security updates and stable.

For example, is it safe interms of not breaking anything on the server if I run this command?

```
su -c '/sbin/chkconfig --level 345 yum on; /sbin/service yum start'
```

This apparently updates the server automatically every day.

As CentOS is supported for 10 years, I will want to make use of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have voiced, you generally do not want to ever enable auto updates on a production server. Instead you have 2 alternatives.

#### Method #1

If the service being offered is tolerant to have some periodic outages you can do what I call "in place updates". This is where you first do a cursory review of what updates are available.

#### Example

```
$ yum list updates
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, langpacks, refresh-packagekit
Updated Packages
clutter.x86_64                                                               1.14.4-6.fc19                                                     updates
kdelibs.x86_64                                                               6:4.11.5-1.fc19                                                   updates
kdelibs-common.x86_64                                                        6:4.11.5-1.fc19                                                   updates
mutter.x86_64                                                                3.8.4-2.fc19                                                      updates
nautilus.x86_64                                                              3.8.2-2.fc19                                                      updates
nautilus-extensions.x86_64                                                   3.8.2-2.fc19                                                      updates
```

I then go through and consider each update and whether the service running on the box will be tolerant to this update or not. Oftentimes the `screen` application or other secondary packages will get updates, usually your service is not directly dependent on these, and so I do this without much concern.

Other updates, such as Apache, might be direct dependents, and so these I scrutinize much more so. I'll often review the packaging logs to see what has changed and also fine the changelogs for that particular version of the package online.

Changes in packages about to be updated:

```
$ sudo yum update nautilus-extensions.x86_64 --changelog
...
...
updates/19/x86_64/other_db                                                                                                     | 5.8 MB  00:00:02     
ChangeLog for: nautilus-3.8.2-2.fc19.x86_64, nautilus-extensions-3.8.2-2.fc19.x86_64
* Mon Dec  9 07:00:00 2013 Matthias Clasen <mclasen@redhat.com> - 3.8.2-2
- Fix transparency issues with the desktop background
- Fix transparency issues with editable labels
...
...
Upgrade  1 Package (+1 Dependent package)

Total download size: 2.6 M
Is this ok [y/d/N]: n
Exiting on user command
Your transaction was saved, rerun it with:
 yum load-transaction /tmp/yum_save_tx.2014-01-11.08-36.3JpVYN.yumtx
```

The `yum` plugin `yum-changelog` is what facilitates this additional output during an update.

```
$ sudo yum install yum-changelog
```

#### Method #2

The more appropriate approach for services that are intolerant of any outages, is to setup a "staging" area, which is an identical system with the same setup. You can then apply the updates there and make sure that they work correctly.

Once they're certified there, you can then safely apply them to your production system.

Answer (score 2):

You **NEVER EVER EVER** want to auto update a production server in my opinion. Not even critical updates.

First test that the updates don't break anything in your testing environment, then, push them into production. checking for updates can be done with monitoring software like Nagios, to get around the whole "I didn't know" issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is the question I've been struggling lately but since I think attacks against common vurnelabilities are increasing nowadays so I've decided to schedule yum-cron to run on our servers every weekend where the use of business app is minimal. In case something happens there's still chance to recover before business hours peak. With Red Hat distro the situation is better since only security updates can applied automatically minimising the amount of installed packages.

But anyway I have used yum-cron now for few months and not faced any problems so far, just remember to use monitoring software like Nagios or Zabbix to see if some part of system is not running as it should. I suggest that you test you prod servers by doing manual update and see if everything goes ok.

Comment: Agreed. Gone are the days when we used to manage two or three servers in an environment; now it's likely to be hundreds. With the significant exploits that we've seen in the last year or two (shellshock, heartbleed, etc.), it's no-longer okay to patch every month. Security patches need to be applied immediately, which just isn't realistic if you're trying to manually patch even 50 servers.

Which are you more afraid of: A small downtime due to a failed patch, or a data leak causing PCI compliance issues, etc.? That's the type of thing that can drown a company in very short order.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to put auto-update option in any Linux production server. So it's better to install updates manually, which ones are really needs.